# CSS Animated Dots Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm currently developing a website for a group, and I'm trying to animate some dots in the word "Loading..." so they blink. I've got the animation working, but for some reason the dots aren't showing up unless I highlight the text with my cursor.

```css
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: .2;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .2;
  }
}

.text span {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.text span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.text span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, rgb(183,183,183));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
```

The "Loading" part of the text is showing up fine though. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: There you go, any idea?

Comment: The way you're going about it now there's not a ton you can do - the text is already transparent, so changing the opacity does nothing.

Comment: any idea on a fix?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: It did! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a color to fall back on for the transparency.

As it stands now, it's already transparent, so the opacity does nothing. If you have a color to go to (not just transparent), it'll show that the relevant percentage, mixed with the gradient. I've done that in the example below using black as the "background".

```css
@keyframes blink {
  /* changes the values here */
  0% {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
}

.text span {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.text span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.text span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.text {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, rgb(183,183,183));
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Loading<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
```